# submit button downloading PHP file instead of sent data to email in contact form

Tags: php, html, action, form-submit, contact-form

I'm trying to make a contact form for my website but when I press submit, the php file is downloaded instead of being run. I am using chrome. I think there's a syntax error but I've messed around with removing, adding and stuff and even when there is no syntax errors, it still downloads the file rather than runs it And, yes...it is the exact name of the php file.

**Html code**

```
<div class="form1" id="form" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-once="true" data-aos-delay="200">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>We're happy to hear from you !</h2>
        </div>
        <form class="form" method="POST" action="form.php">
            <div class="contact-us">
                <h2>Contact Us !</h2>
            </div><hr>
            <div class="parent">
                <div class = "Name">
                    <label for = "fname">First Name:</label>
                    <input type = "text" maxlength="15" name = "fname"   placeholder="First name" required>
                </div>
                <div class = "Name">
                    <label for = "lname">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type = "text" maxlength="20" name = "lname"  placeholder="Second name" required>
                </div>
            </div>
                
            <div class = "email">
                <label for = "email">Email:<br></label>
                <input type = "email" minlength="8" name = "email"  placeholder="Your email" required>
            </div>
            
            <p class = "comment">
                <label for="message">Comments:<br></label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="10" rows="5" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
            </p>
            <div class="submit">
                <input  type="submit" class="submit-btn"  value="Send Us"  >
            </div>
        </form>
```

**php code**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];// Get fName value from HTML Form
        $lname = $_POST['lname']; // Get lName value from HTML Form
        $email_id = $_POST['email']; // Get Email Value
        $msg = $_POST['message']; // Get Message Value
        $to = "...@gmail.com"; // You can change here your Email
        $subject = "'$name' has been sent a mail"; // This is your subject
         
        // HTML Message Starts here
        $message ="
        <html>
            <body>
                <table style='width:600px;'>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style='width:150px'><strong>FName: </strong></td>
                            <td style='width:400px'>$fname</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style='width:150px'><strong>LName: </strong></td>
                            <td style='width:400px'>$lname</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style='width:150px'><strong>Email ID: </strong></td>
                            <td style='width:400px'>$email_id</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style='width:150px'><strong>Message: </strong></td>
                            <td style='width:400px'>$msg</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
        ";
        // HTML Message Ends here
         
        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
 
        // More headers
        $headers .= 'From: Admin <...@gmail.com>' . "\r\n"; // Give an email id on which you want get a reply. User will get a mail from this email id
         
        if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
            // Message if mail has been sent
            echo "<script>
                    alert('Mail has been sent Successfully.');
                </script>";
        }
 
        else{
            // Message if mail has been not sent
            echo "<script>
                    alert('EMAIL FAILED');
                </script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your webserver isn't configured to execute PHP files; this has nothing to do with the code you've posted, but is due to missing configuration in whatever webserver you have set up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+downloads+instead+of+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: you will also need to add name="submit" to your submit button since you are checking if the $_POST['submit'] is set.

Comment: You are testing name="submit" - it is not a good idea to name anything in a form "submit" if you ever plan on submitting using JavaScript. You still need to name the submit button and test it is set - so `<input  type="submit" id="submit-btn"  value="Send Us"  >` and   `if(isset($_POST['submit-btn']))`

Answer (score 0):

If you can add this to your `apache config` file

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

That will sort out your problem

HOW TO - https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/working_with_the_apache_config_file.html

Also make sure you are running the code on a server environment like wamp or xamp. If you are working offline.